# Why is the number on "find the smallest missing positive number in an N element array problem" always <= N + 1?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Like for example the smallest missing number on these [LeetCode examples](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/) below are always between 1 and *N* where *N* is the array size.
What is the proof of that?

> Given an unsorted integer array `nums`, find the smallest missing positive integer.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> > Input: `nums = [1,2,0]`
> > Output: `3`
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> > Input: `nums = [3,4,-1,1]`
> > Output: `2`
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> > Input: `nums = [7,8,9,11,12]`
> > Output: `1`
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - `0 <= nums.length <= 300`
> - -2<sup>31</sup> `<= nums[i] <=` 2<sup>31</sup> - 1

Comment: Give the description of the problem you are mentioning. Do not assume everyone else to have 
exact reference of what you are referring to.

Comment: Please explain your problem statement more.

Comment: Very well then I will put some examples to refer what I mean to my question.

Comment: Either an array with exactly N positive integers contains 1,2,3,...,N or it doesn't. Break your proof up into two cases. You should be able to prove it (which seems to be a homework problem) based on that hint.

Comment: Nope it's not a homework it's from leetcode exercises . I am currently self learning on programming exercises on the current moment . I already saw the answer of that problem on Youtube but people tend to avoid proving that missing positive number <= N .

Comment: Probably not proved since, thought of the right way, it is obvious. If the array contains all the numbers in the range 1,...,N, then of course N+1 is the smallest missing number. Otherwise, it *doesn't* contains all numbers in the range 1,...,N. In other words it is *missing* one of the elements, hence the smallest missing positive number is < =N hence <= N+1.

Comment: I guess this is this an application of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) in reverse (with voids.)

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that you can't fit more integer than `N` integers in an array. If you fill it with all indexes with the smallest positive integers out there, of course, your answer will be `N + 1`, otherwise it will always be smaller or equal to `N`.

I think a few examples will explain it better than words

### Array filled with 0s

`[0,0,0]`

The smallest missing positive integer for this one will be `1`, thus smaller than the size of the array + 1.

### Array filled sequentially with each index storing its value + 1

`[1,2,3]`

Here, the smallest missing positive integer will be `4`, and it is equal to `N + 1`.

### Array filled with bigger numbers

`[100,101,102]`

Here, the smallest missing positive integer is `1` and is of course smaller than the size of the array.